# English time-format in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, culture, kendo-scheduler

I'm using the Kendo Scheduler in my ASP.NET MVC5 website.

Based on the culture-settings of the browser and the pc, I change the language of the controls from Kendo (With the kendo-culture-js files)

When I want to change the language of the scheduler to "English" ('en'), the time-format is very weird.

In the image below, you can see it.
Instead of AM and PM:

- In the left column with the times, it shows "A2" or "P2".
- In the add-form, it uses "AM" and "PM". As it should be...
- When I save the event, the time in the event shows "A7" or "P7".

Note: I'm dutch, so I have no idea if those things have a meaning.

[image: Kendo Scheduler]

The Add-form fills my "event"-model in my ASP.NET-website.
When I check the values in my model, it shows "AM" and "PM". As it should be...

Does anyone know why it shows "A2","P2","A7","P7"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kendo's [date/time](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting) formatting is almost, but not quite, the same as .NET's, (And includes several significant omissions: a real problem when the MVC helpers use the same format on server and client). Also note: that looks like *American* formatting. In England we use something more sane (15/07/2015 13:58).

Comment: What formatting string is being specified in each case?

Comment: @Richard:
startTime.toLocaleTimeString('en')

Comment: I've used the "toLocaleTimeString", because I want that the time and date-format changes as the language

Answer (score 1):

From comment:

> ```
>  startTime.toLocaleTimeString('en')
> ```

Which will fallback to en-US and use a format string of `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`. This will render as something like `07/15/2015 02:05 pm`.

However it appears, on the client side, this is being passed to Kendo's date formatting function, for which all but one character is treated as a literal. But `m` is the minute without leading zero, so is being replaced.

Either do all the formatting server side or all client side. Doing a bit of both will create problems like this. Unfortunately with JavaScript's limited date handling and Kendo's limitations this is hard to get right.

Comment: I don't get it why the "m" is replaced by a 2 and in the event by a 7?

Comment: `m` is a meta char in Kendo's date formatting ("The minute, from 0 through 59."): without code I cannot be sure but your symptoms are consistent with the formatted date being passed through `kendo.toString`.

Comment: This is my code to display the time: 

kendo.toString(date, date.toLocaleTimeString('en'))

Comment: @ceuben That is wrong: you are formatting it twice, using the output of `toLocaleTimeString` as the format for `kendo.toString`. But `toLocaleTimeString` returns a formatted date, not the format to use. Hence "07/15/2015 02:05 pm" becomes "07/15/2015 02:05 p5" because `kendo.toString` sees the "m" and replaces it with the minutes value from its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the date like this:

```
kendo.toString(start, start.toLocaleTimeString('en'))
```

But it has to be:

```
kendo.toString(start.toLocaleTimeString('en'))
```